# populate 2nd dropdown by select first dropdown value in php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

> I am declared two select. once i select value in first select then i
>   will fetch value in second select.

```
<?php
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT row1 FROM information");?>
<select id='select1'>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
if($row['row1']!=NULL)
{
echo "<option value='$row[row1]'>$row[row1]</option>";
}
}?>
</select><br/><br/>
<?php
//*******************************************  
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT column1 FROM information");
echo "<select id='select2'>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
if($row['column1']!=NULL)
{
echo "<option value='$row[column1]'>$row[column1]</option>";
}
}?>
</select>
```

Comment: You'll need to use ajax to get the values for the second select, the server, running php, won't be able to know what the client, browser, has selected from the first select until it has been selected by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. Use jQuery + ajax to build dynamically second select after first (onselect event)
2. Submit form or redirect user to same page with selected value from first select and if it is given (check in PHP from $_GET or $_POST) and if it is - generate second select with this info